# Analysis of Gravity Model Residuals

Tags: r, econometrics, residuals, poisson-regression

**Background:** I am running a gravity model (very basic: trade flow ~ GDP(i) + GDP(j) + pop (i) + pop(j) + D(ij)) with a Poisson quasi-maximum likelihood model (PQML).  I have already converted everything to natural log form (Log in R) and ran the model.

My issue is that I want to see the possible trade gains if two countries were trading, they currently have not been trading formally for the past 24 years.  Their values are in the model as a 0 trade flow, thus the use of the PQML.

Currently, that data set is made up of all nations the countries trade with in particular goods (disaggregated flows) over the past 24 years.  I cannot go farther back as one country gains its independence 24 years ago so this is the data I am stuck with.

Since they have zero trade flows the negative residuals should be possible gains from trade they would experience. Following Residuals = Observation - Prediction.  To double check my the residuals I recorded the `predict()` values for each observation along with the `fitted()`.  Nothing is adding up and even if it did I am not sure how to interpret the negative residual outcome.

Here is an example of code for one of the goods:

```
GravVegReg<-glm(Log.Trade.Value ~ Log.gdp_o + Log.gdp_d + Log.pop_o + Log.pop_d+Log.distw, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), finalVEGRedo.data)
VegResid<-residuals(glm(Log.Trade.Value ~ Log.gdp_o + Log.gdp_d + Log.pop_o + Log.pop_d+Log.distw, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), finalVEGRedo.data, na.action = na.exclude))
VegPred<-predict(glm(Log.Trade.Value ~ Log.gdp_o + Log.gdp_d + Log.pop_o + Log.pop_d+Log.distw, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), finalVEGRedo.data, na.action = na.exclude))
VegFit<-fitted(glm(Log.Trade.Value ~ Log.gdp_o + Log.gdp_d + Log.pop_o + Log.pop_d+Log.distw, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"), finalVEGRedo.data, na.action = na.exclude))
summary(GravVegReg)
print(GravVegReg)
finalVEGRedo.data$residPoiRegLnY <-VegResid
finalVEGRedo.data$PredPoiRegLnY<-VegPred
finalVEGRedo.data$FitPoiRegLnY<-VegFit
```

**Question:** So I added the residuals, predicted, and fitted back to my data set to help me analyze individual observations a little easier.

[image: output in view]
The area outlined in blue are observations without a zero trade flow and the ones in red are the observations with a zero trade flow.

So it comes down to if my residuals are correct are they transformed back with exp(|residual|)? Or do I need to reassess and figure out why my predict and fitted values are so different and then transform the residuals out of Ln form?

Comment: Also I figured it out, I screwed up and was using a Ln(trade value) instead of just (trade value).  So with the residual or the fitted it should be the trade value forgone. This technique works but just make sure that if you are using it to get your model right.  But residuals and fitted values from the observed work to model forgone trade flows when zero trade flows are present.  (Hope this answers other people's questions as well)